# Многострочный текст в теге sup

Tags: html, css

Задача - задать цену с рублями и копейками в верхнем индексе. Однако под копейками должен быть текст баллов.

[image: как на картинке]

Без второй строки текста всё решалось тегом . Однако он не подразумевает многострочного текста.

```
4<sup>79</sup>
```

Как сделать текст как на картинке?

Comment: только так и можно или таблицей

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j1ykr8Lb/19/  вот так - но надо доработать

Comment: @МаксимЛенский оформите ответом может быть)?

Comment: @PauloBerezini можешь доработать и ответить сам

Comment: а что там дорабатывать только шрифт подобрать, готовый ответ

Comment: @PauloBerezini  я же говорю ...пользуйся

Comment: @PauloBerezini то есть, всё решается через  vertical-align:top; и смещение? оформите ответом, пожалуйста, чтобы я смог отметить как верный ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил шрифт

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.a,
.b {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: red;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.b {
  line-height: 15px;
  transform: translateY(30px);
}

.a p {
  font-size: 12em;
  transform: translateY(-30px);
}

.b p {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.b .c {
  font-size: 4em;
}

.b .d {
  transform: translateY(20px);
}

.noukan {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
}
 p {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; /* Шрифт с засечками */
    font-style: italic; /* Курсивное начертание */
   }
```

```html
<div class="noukan">
  <div class="a">
    <p>4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <p class="c">79</p>
    <p class="d">баллов</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

p.s. Спасибо за ответ  [Максим Ленский](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/33274/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Answer (score 2):

А зачем столько извращений?

Прекрасно работает с минимальными усилиями:

```css
.test sup {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">4<sup>79<i>Баллов</i></sup></div>
```

Фиддл (слегка украсил шрифты, чтобы размер примерно соответствовал. Подгонять под нужные габариты не стал): https://jsfiddle.net/cq52ky47/

---

Если в `<sup>` залезать нельзя (мало ли что позволено, а что нет), то можно вообще слово "Баллов" в псевдоэлемент засунуть, да еще и поиграть со склонением:

https://jsfiddle.net/fcw6e1a3/5/